# phpinfo() shows v5.4 though v5.6 is installed

Tags: php

I have an RPI and I just installed PHP 5.6 on it:

> pi@rpi ~ $ php -v
>
> PHP 5.6.10 (cli) (built: May  6 2016 23:29:10)

But `phpinfo()` still returns the old version `PHP Version 5.4.45-07`. Of course I can't use any features available from version >5.5.

Comment: Are you running phpinfo() from the CLI, or through a web browser?

Comment: Have you restarted Apache?

Comment: Running `phpinfo()` from web browser. Restarted apache and the server as well many times since the upgrade.

Comment: If I am not wrong php cli is different than apache php. You need to install php 5.6 for apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent a week or so on Google, but couldn't solve it. Finally upgrading from `Wheezy` to `Jessie`, which has `php 5.6` available by default, sorted this out.